# Custom frame/decoration for specific X window

Tags: c++, image, window, x11, window-decoration

Is there any way to apply or have custom frames (images) around specific X windows?

For example, in **xfwm4** and **fvwm** (window managers)  it's possible to have a specific window decoration for a window with different images, one at the bottom, other at the top, etc. examples:

For [xfwm4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orH38.png) and [fvwm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMTxs.png).

Obviously if it was that easy, I'd just use either of them, however, I do think that a singular program could handle it instead of needing to change the whole window manager.

I'm currently using **dwm** and there   are ways to change the colour and thickness of border, and that's it. If I was better at **C** I could create a rule to draw images around specific X windows with specific WM_CLASS, but that's too much for me now, **so any help is really appreciated.**

---

An alternative solution would be to draw a single image (from a file) bigger than the X window behind it and make it to follow the X window position, *and maybe the size as well* (that's harder, so it's not really that necessary)

I started writing a **C++** program to do that, but that may take too much time since **C++** still a new tool to me and looking at how **xfwm4** handles this.